# C hashtable library natively supporting multiple values per key

Tags: c, hashtable

If you want to store multiple values for a key, there's always the possibility of tucking a list in between the hashtable and the values. However, I figure that to be rather inefficient, as:

The hashtable has to resolve collisions, anyway, so does some kind of list walking. Instead of stopping when it found the first key in a bucket that matches the query key, it could just continue to walk the bucket, presumably giving better cache performance than walking yet another list after following yet another indirection.

Is anyone aware of library implementations that support this by default (and ideally are also otherwise shiny, fast, hashtables as well as BSD or similarly licensed)? I've looked through a couple of libraries but none did what I wanted, glib's [datasets](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Datasets.html) coming closest, though storing records, not lists.

Comment: Surely walking a single linked list is the same as jumping to a new list, in terms of cache performance?  In both cases, you're just following pointers around.

Comment: The bucket has a fair chance of already being in cache, a separate list not so much. The whole thing of course depends on implementation, in the case where the bucket itself is a mere linked list you're completely right.

Comment: A quick Google gave me this: http://uthash.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @WoLpH , from the docs: "As with any hash, every item must have a unique key. Your application must enforce key uniqueness. Before you add an item to the hash table, you must first know (if in doubt, check!) that the key is not already in use. You can check whether a key already exists in the hash table using HASH_FIND."

Comment: @barsoap: you're totally right, I read over that part. I will continue the search :)

Answer (score 1):

So… something like a [multimap](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Multimap.html)?

[Libgee](http://live.gnome.org/Libgee), building off of [GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/), provides a [MultiMap](http://people.gnome.org/~dvillevalois/libgee/doc/gee-1.0/Gee.MultiMap.html).  (It's written in Vala, but that is converted to plain C.)

Comment: Semantically, yes, operationally, libgee tucks a list in between the hashtable and the values, as evident in abstractmultimap.vala:86